# Changing the height anchor of TableView based on the data/number of cells

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to change the TableView height to full screen if there is enough data otherwise make the height equal to the content (so you don't need to scroll). In the picture below, the tableview's height should end at the last cell but as you can see it's at the bottom of the view. I don't want the height of the circle view to change. (I know my tableview's bottom anchor is not set correctly but I'm running out of ideas)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ELZ.jpg) is the current output

I've try changing the priority of the anchors, and various other things but could not get the desired result. I tried adding the code below after tableview.reloadData() but that caused the tableview's height anchor to be too large resulting in the height going off screen.

```swift
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

```swift
private func setupConstraint() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(attendanceCircleView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            attendanceCircleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            attendanceCircleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.95),
            attendanceCircleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            attendanceCircleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: attendanceCircleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.95),
            tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // create a height Constraint of tableview 


  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.reloadTableView()
    }

  func updateTableiewConstraints() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01, execute: {
            let height : CGFloat = self.tableView.contentSize.height
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        })
    }
```

NOTE : 
1. set tableview top constraint should be greater than 0.

2. set priority of tableView height Constraint reduce to 900.

Comment: Your code does absolutely nothing because you have an uncalled function. Even if you call that, it will make the table's height to go offscreen, as the OP tried.

Comment: I still don't think it does anything? Where do you call this function `updateTableiewConstraints `?

Comment: @Tj3n You call that function after reloading the tableview data.

Comment: It did not work. The content of the tableview goes off screen because the height is too big

Comment: @SomeCoder set tableView Top constraint greater than Zero. it will never goes off screen.

Comment: I changed it to `tableView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: attendanceCircleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)` but now it's completely gone. Is that what you meant? I found another solution that works

Comment: It's causing a huge gap between the circleView and the tableview

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by doing the following.

```swift
let tableViewBottomAnchor = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
tableViewBottomAnchor.priority = .defaultLow
tableViewBottomAnchor.isActive = true
```

and calculating the height constraint after calling `tableView.reloadData()`

```swift
let tableViewMaxHeight = self.tableView.frame.height
let contentTableViewHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
let height = tableViewMaxHeight <= contentTableViewHeight ? tableViewMaxHeight: contentTableViewHeight
self.tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:height).isActive = true
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: I think there is a simpler solution. I'll try messing around with it later.